# Matrix Vector Product

Tags: linear-algebra

I am reading a book on [Linear Algebra](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=mYVeAQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Linear+Algebra:+Step+by+Step&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjt5vSB5MPnAhVDfH0KHeeUC0oQ6AEIKDAA#v=snippet&q=matrix%20vector%20product&f=false)

On page 47, the author introduces the concept of matrix times a vector as follows:

[image]

At this point, the author hasn't introduced the concept of matrix multiplication.

Can someone explain what's going on in the highlighted part? Particularly, I have trouble understanding -> `(2 2) (x y)` part. As I said, the author hasn't introduced matrix multiplication at this point. Is he going to solve this using dot product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are multiplying first with first, second with second etc. and then adding them together, like in the dot product. In general, $$\begin{pmatrix}x_1&x_2&\cdots&x_n\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}y_1\\y_2\\ \vdots\\y_n\end{pmatrix}=x_1y_1+x_2y_2+\ldots+x_ny_n$$

Comment: So we are taking the dot product right?

Comment: @Cody I would rather say that it is "like" the dot product, because in the dot product you are multiplying vectors from the same set, while here the first argument (row) comes from a different set than the second (column) - even if you can identify one with the other.

Comment: @StinkingBishop But isn't the result of this multiplication still a matrice whereas dot product is a scalar? Shouldn't we say that the determinant of this matrix multiplication equlals the dot product?

Comment: @user599310 Indeed, the product of a row matrix and a column matrix is a $1\times 1$ matrix, which is here identified with its one and only element. However, for the OP it may be confusing, as they say that they have never introduced matrix multiplication. So, they introduce multiplication of a row by a column *as above* (with a result being a scalar) and then they can use that to define full matrix multiplication. (At that stage of understanding matrices, it is also not wise to mention determinants, IMHO.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes to do matrix multiplication you start by multiplying the first **row** of the matrix to the left with the first **column** of the matrix to the right as dot/scalar product; this will give you the first entry of the matrix.

For the second entry below the first one you multiply the second **row** of the matrix to the left with the first **column** of the matrix to the right.